# incrementar variable al clickear un botón en html

Tags: javascript, html

estaba intentando programar un poequeño juego al estilo "idle clicker" ya que pense que era un desafio facil para un principiante.

sin embargo, me quede trabado al intentar incrementar una variabla al hacer click en un boton de html. este es mi codigo:

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Idle clicker</title>
        <script src="sketch.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onClick="addlvl(Alvl);">alvl+</button>
        <button onClick="addlvl(Blvl);">blvl+</button>
        <button onClick="addlvl(Clvl);">clvl+</button>
        <button onClick="addlvl(Dlvl);">dlvl+</button>
        <button onClick="addlvl(Flvl);">flvl+</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

js:

```
var Alvl = 0;
var Blvl = 0;
var Clvl = 0;
var Dlvl = 0;
var Flvl = 0;

function addlvl(v){
    v++;
    console.log(Alvl);
}
```

quiero que cada vez que clickeo el primer boton, a Alvl se le sume 1.

al clickearlo 10 veces, el valor debería ser 10.

Alguien puede ayudarme con esta situacion? desde ya agradezco todos los dislikes o downvotes que voy a recibir.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes lograr lo que quieres con un `switch()` asi:

```js
var Alvl = 0;
var Blvl = 0;
var Clvl = 0;
var Dlvl = 0;
var Flvl = 0;

function addlvl(v){
    switch(v) {
      case 'A':
        console.log(++Alvl);
        break;
      case 'B':
        console.log(++Blvl);
        break;
      case 'C':
        console.log(++Clvl);
        break;
      case 'D':
        console.log(++Dlvl);
        break;
      case 'F':
        console.log(++Flvl);
        break;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Idle clicker</title>
        <script src="sketch.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onClick="addlvl('A');">alvl+</button>
        <button onClick="addlvl('B');">blvl+</button>
        <button onClick="addlvl('C');">clvl+</button>
        <button onClick="addlvl('D');">dlvl+</button>
        <button onClick="addlvl('F');">flvl+</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias! no estaba al tanto de esta funcion, sin duda es util!

Answer (score 1):

Debes ingresar a los elementos del html y con eso puedes convertir el parametro string en la variable que declaraste, con esto puedes hacer la suma que necesitas

```js
var Alvl = 0;
var Blvl = 0;
var Clvl = 0;
var Dlvl = 0;
var Flvl = 0;

function addlvl(v){    
    console.log(++this[v]);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Idle clicker</title>
        <script src="sketch.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onClick="addlvl('Alvl');">alvl+</button>
        <button onClick="addlvl('Blvl');">blvl+</button>
        <button onClick="addlvl('Clvl');">clvl+</button>
        <button onClick="addlvl('Dlvl');">dlvl+</button>
        <button onClick="addlvl('Flvl');">flvl+</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ya con eso puedes probar cada una de los clic para que veas el resultado

Comment: entonces lo unico que me faltaba era un simple    '    para convertir el string en variable?

Comment: Solo tenias que enviar los parametros del atributo onclick en string y ya en JS atrapas ese valor, la variable this se refiere al boton al que le diste clic es un arreglo y solo le dices que seleccione la variable this[v] esto es el equivalente a la variable declarada en JS y solo agregas el ++ para que aumente

Comment: ... _al clickearlo 10 veces, el valor debería ser 10._ Al hacer clic la primera vez el contador inicia en 0, por ende en el clic 10 mostraría 9... Sólo digo, si a @pedro_taq le vale así, no hay lío!

Comment: Es cierto, agrega el ++ antes del this[v] con eso empieza el contador en 1, gracias @DjCrazy no me habia dado cuenta

Comment: @DjCrazy a decir verdad si, pero para el proposito de este juego, asumo que empieza en cero, por lo tanto el primer click lo convertiria en un 1 ;)

Comment: @TheVicShow me ha surgido otra pregunta, prometo que sera la ultima por hoy ;). si quiero que en vez de aumentar de a 1 cada vez, aumente segun el valor de otra variable, asi pudiendo sumar 10, o 100 con un solo click, como lo haria?

Comment: No te apures, estamos aquí para ayudar, Seria una variable random? o tu le indicarías cual variable?